# equivalent of args() from R in python

Tags: python, r

is there any equivalent of the [`args()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gdata/versions/2.18.0/topics/Args) function from R in python?

> Display function argument names and corresponding default values...

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the `help` built-in function

```
>>> help(print)
Help on built-in function print in module builtins:

print(...)
    print(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)

    Prints the values to a stream, or to sys.stdout by default.
    Optional keyword arguments:
    file:  a file-like object (stream); defaults to the current sys.stdout.
    sep:   string inserted between values, default a space.
    end:   string appended after the last value, default a newline.
    flush: whether to forcibly flush the stream.
```

or alternatively you can get it as a string

```
>>> help_print = print.__doc__
>>> print(help_print)
print(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)

Prints the values to a stream, or to sys.stdout by default.
Optional keyword arguments:
file:  a file-like object (stream); defaults to the current sys.stdout.
sep:   string inserted between values, default a space.
end:   string appended after the last value, default a newline.
flush: whether to forcibly flush the stream.
```

### NOTE

this doesn't reqiure functions with docstrings:

```
>>> def foo(a: int):
...     print(a)
...
>>> help(foo)
Help on function foo in module __main__:

foo(a: int)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use inspect module, here is an example:

```
>>> import inspect                                  

>>> def foo(bar=0): 
...     pass                                        

>>> inspect.getfullargspec(foo)                     
FullArgSpec(args=['bar'], varargs=None, varkw=None, defaults=(0,), kwonlyargs=[], kwonlydefaults=None, annotations={})
```